# Problem With Reversing Each Number In An Array In Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, reverse, do-while

I'm trying to reverse each number in an Integer array using do-while, but I get NullPointerException error.I'm trying to reverse each element in this array: for instance if this is my array:{12,34,56} then the result must be:{21,43,65}.Can someone please help me with this?

```
public class Reverse {
  public int[] revCalculator(int[] number) {
    int[] reverse = null;
    for (int j = 0; j < number.length; j++) {
        do {
            reverse[j] = reverse[j] * 10 + number[j] % 10;
            number[j] /= 10;
        } while (number[j] > 0);
    }
    return reverse;
  }
}

public class ShowReverse {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // instantiation
    // -----------------------------------------
    Reverse rev = new Reverse();
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("Enter The Number Of Elements: ");
    int len = in.nextInt();
    int[] numbers = new int[len];


    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter Number: ");
        numbers[i] = in.nextInt();
    }


    int[] result = rev.revCalculator(numbers);

    // shows the result
    // -----------------------------------------
    System.out.println("THE REVERSE WOULD BE: ");
    System.out.print(result);

  }
}
```

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2Laz.png)

Comment: int[] reverse = null;
reverse isn't initialized

Comment: As you see, I've used it...but it's no use

Comment: You can't use it if you don't create it first. Which is why you get a NPE here.

Comment: `reverse` is being set to null.  You can't treat a null like an array.  You need to initialize `reverse` to be an _actual_ array: `int[] reverse = new int[number.length]'`

Comment: thanks ..could you plz check the pic and guide me through the result?

Comment: @Rojin Can you even pass an integer array to `System.out.print`? I would wrap your code in a `try-catch` block and view any `exception` messages you may be receiving.

Comment: you Should debug code extensively before asking others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't initialize your variable `reverseArray`, initialize it like so:

UPDATE, I see what you are trying to do, you want to reverse the values of your array, not the array itself

```
public int[] revCalculator(int[] number) {
    int[] reverse = new int[number.length]; //Initialize it to the same size as the passed in arary
    //int[] reverse = null; //Problem
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int j = 0; j < number.length; j++) 
    {
        //You could convert the number to string then reverse it and use parseInt() int
        reverse[j] = parseInt(sb.append(number[j].toString()).reverse().toString());
        //Clear the StringBuilder object
        sb.setLength(0);

    }
    return reverse;
}
```

Comment: thanks but now I got a problem with showing me the result ...could you plz check the picture?

Comment: thanks ...IT HELPED...all I had to do was to iterate while printing the result!

Comment: @Rojin Glad I could help, also I updated my answer as creating a new `StringBuilder` on each iteration is wasteful, it is more efficient that if you go the `StringBuilder` route / solution, you just create one `StringBuilder` and clear the buffer inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend initializing the reverse array to an array of the same length as the number array.

```
int[] reverse = new int[number.length];
```

Comment: now I got a problem with showing me the result ...could you plz check the picture?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of changes that you have to make:

1. initialize reverse array `int[] reverse = new int[number.length];`
2. `System.out.print(result);` would give you the address of result array. You have to show the elements of the array.

   ```
   int[] result = new int[numbers.length];
   result = rev.revCalculator(numbers);

   // shows the result
   // -----------------------------------------
   System.out.println("THE REVERSE WOULD BE: ");
   //System.out.print(result);
   for(int i = 0 ; i<result.length; i++)
       System.out.println(result[i]);
   ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot....I edited my code after I found out I could not directly print out an array's elements ;))